# Strategy entry does not go long at the open as expected

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I am new here and would appreciate some help with Pine script. I am trying out the pine strategy. I stumbled upon a problem. My script is not behaving as expected. The strategy I am testing is buy at today’s open and sell at today's close.

The problem is

1. the entry does not happen at the expected open
2. I don't see any trading in a few candles.

I don’t seem to understand what mistake I am making. Appreciate if you can point me in the correct direction. Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT1YB.png)

I tried the following script

```
//@version=5
strategy("Buy at Open, Sell at Close", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close=true)


if  time > timestamp("2022-05-01T00:00:00Z")
    strategy.entry("LetsGoLong", strategy.long, limit = open )
    strategy.exit("TimeToExit", "LetsGoLong", limit = close)
```

I was expecting to go long at open and exit at close.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting to enter a trade when a candle opens, you are thinking it wrong.

You are placing a limit entry order at the open price of the previous candle. That will be evaluated on the next bar.

Or you can think it this way: You are placing a limit entry order at the open price of the current bar, when that bar is closed.

Comment: I think i understand, do you know how i can change the current code to to go long at open and exit at close please?